Draw data ellipses at spatial locations
I have a data objects that contains a sample of measurements obtained for two air pollutants at a series of monitoring stations. I also have the spatial coordinates of these stations. For example:
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.2, GDAL 3.7.2, PROJ 9.3.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(ggplot2)

monitoring_stations <- st_sf(
  data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C")),
  geometry = st_sfc(
    st_point(c(1, 1)),
    st_point(c(2, 2)),
    st_point(c(3, 3))
  )
)
values <- data.frame(
  ID = sample(c("A", "B", "C"), size = 100, replace = TRUE), 
  value1 = runif(100), 
  value2 = runif(100)
)

Edit
Update displaying the desired output.
I'm sorry but the description of the problem probably wasn't clear. I don't need to overlap the point-level data (i.e. the spatial coordinates of the monitoring stations) and the data-ellipses on the same plot. I would like to create a map displaying the spatial locations of the monitoring stations and the corresponding data ellipses at each station. For example (using similar data as the previous example):
covs <- by(values, values[["ID"]], function(x) cov(x[, 2:3]))
plot(st_coordinates(monitoring_stations), pch = 16, xlim = c(0.5, 3.5), ylim = c(0.5, 3.5), axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
ellipse(st_coordinates(monitoring_stations)[1, ], shape = covs[[1]], radius = 1, center.pch = 1)
ellipse(st_coordinates(monitoring_stations)[2, ], shape = covs[[2]], radius = 1, center.pch = 1)
ellipse(st_coordinates(monitoring_stations)[3, ], shape = covs[[3]], radius = 1, center.pch = 1)


Clearly, the previous code is working, but it has several limitations when I need to adjust other settings of the plot based on other characteristics of the data. Therefore, if possible, I would like a solution which is integrated into the ggplot2/tmap/mapsf framework.
Original
(full_data <- merge(monitoring_stations, values, by = "ID"))
#> Simple feature collection with 100 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 3 ymax: 3
#> CRS:           NA
#> First 10 features:
#>    ID     value1     value2    geometry
#> 1   A 0.13221654 0.76275479 POINT (1 1)
#> 2   A 0.67336289 0.29259564 POINT (1 1)
#> 3   A 0.25384031 0.35145494 POINT (1 1)
#> 4   A 0.99337433 0.30237615 POINT (1 1)
#> 5   A 0.68685394 0.42133826 POINT (1 1)

I can create a plot displaying the data ellipse for each monitoring station, for example:
ggplot(full_data, aes(value1, value2)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_ellipse(aes(group = ID, col = ID))


I can also display the spatial locations of the monitoring stations:
ggplot(full_data) + 
  geom_sf()


However, I would like to merge the two previous plots creating a map that represent 1) the monitoring stations (as dots); 2) the data ellipse at each monitoring station overlapped on that map. How can I accomplish this task using R and ggplot2 or any other package?

Unfortunately, I do not understand the desired output (anymore). If truefor othersall, you might consider to reshape your question completely? Deleted my answer. The data ellipses should be data-driven, i.e. (id-grouped values)? And then?

Shifting the centres of the three ellipses caculated on the ID-grouped values to the locations of the monitoring_stations, such that the shapes and radii are maintained?

@Friede, something similar to what is accomplished by the R package scatterpie but I would like to display data ellipses instead of pie plots.

Edit based on OP's question update
When working with geographical data, it is best practice to make all of your data sf objects. Mixing geoms can lead to issues. Similarly, if you are using sf objects, you should routinely assign a CRS. It makes things more robust. It is also a good habit to use longitude and latitude (lon/lat in this example) as coordinate variable names.
Based on your sample values, I am using WGS84/EPSG:4326 as the CRS, but you need to ensure you choose the correct one for your actual data. I have created a more representative version of full_data, one that assigns station ID by proximity rather than being entirely random.
When plotting multiple data sources, you simply declare each dataset and its associated aesthetics in individual geoms.
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Monitoring stations with CRS
monitoring_stations <- st_sf(data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C")),
                             geometry = st_sfc(st_point(c(1, 1)),
                                               st_point(c(2, 2)),
                                               st_point(c(3, 3))),
                             crs = 4326) %>%
  st_as_sf()

# Add row names to monitoring_stations for left_join
monitoring_stations$ID1 <- as.integer(row.names(monitoring_stations))

# Full data with same CRS as monitoring_stations
set.seed(1)
full_data <- data.frame(value1 = runif(100, 0, 4), 
                        value2 = runif(100, 0, 4)) %>%
  mutate(lon = value1,
         lat = value2) %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("value1", "value2"), crs = 4326) %>%
  mutate(ID = st_nearest_feature(., monitoring_stations)) %>%
  left_join(., st_drop_geometry(monitoring_stations),
            by = join_by(ID == ID1)) %>%
  mutate(ID = ID.y) %>%
  select(-ends_with(".y"))

ggplot() +
  #geom_sf(data = full_data) +
  geom_sf(data = monitoring_stations, aes(colour = ID), size = 4) +
  stat_ellipse(data = full_data, 
               aes(x = lon, y = lat, group = ID, colour = ID)) +
  scale_colour_discrete(name = "Monitoring stations\nand Ellipses") +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 8))



Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't really accomplish the desired goal. Sorry that my previous description wasn't clear; I updated the question showcasing an example of the desired output and explaining its limitations.

More or less yes but, to be honest, it feels quite unnatural to transform value1 and value2 into spatial objects (while they are just measurements of some quantities recorded at certain monitoring stations) and perform all the other operations. If you want to see another example of the desired goal, I would like to accomplish more or less the same output as the R package scatterpie, but with data ellipses instead of pie plots. In any case, thank you very much for your answer!

@agila - now it is clearer. From your choice of values and plot example, it made it appear that value1 and value2 were spatial coordinates. Can you update your question with an example scatterpie plot? It's still not entirely clear what you are asking.

Something like the last figure at this vignette, whereas instead of displaying the pie plot at each location, I want to show the data ellipse. The two plots are clearly used in different contexts, but I hope that displays the disired output.
